# discord bot next line with space

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a broadcast bot and I hope it can switch to the next line by adding space between sentences

```js
if (args[0] == '/bc') {
 message.channel.send(
  '@everyone\n' +
   args[1] +
   '\n' +
   args[2] +
   '\n' +
   args[3] +
   '\n' +
   args[4] +
   '\n' +
   args[5] +
   '\n' +
   args[6] +
   '\n' +
   args[7] +
   '\n' +
   args[8]
 );
 message.delete();
}
```

But when I type `/bc testing 857857 abcdefg`
it will show:

```
@everyone
testing
857857
abcdefg
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Is there any way to make it works better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
message.channel.send(`@everyone\n${args.slice(1).join('\n')}`);
```

```js
const args = ['/bc', '123456', 'testing', 'hello', 'world'];

console.log(`@everyone\n${args.slice(1).join('\n')}`);
```

This will combine every `arg` element by a line break.